Disable red underline in notes app
I tried to disable spellcheck and grammer check in the notes app but still I see red underlines in the notes app:

I've also checked the keyboard settings in system preferences and made sure all spelling checks were turned off.

How can I remove the red underlines and yellow words in notes app macos sequoia 15.1.0?


The issue was the latest notes app update has math calculations autocompletion which can be disabled from Format > Math Results > Off:

